# Set Javascript cookie from google location permission?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cookies

I have a feature on a site that gives the user the telephone number of their closest branch of shop based on their current location via the google-maps api.

When the page loads for the first time, the browser automatically asks the user if they would like to share their location.  That's all fine, except some browsers don't handle it as well as others and continually ask the user when the move from page to page (the number is on every page).

So is there a way I can set a cookie based on weather or not they gave permission and only display the automatic 'this site would like to use your current location' message if the cookie has expired after say, a month?

It is particularly bad on smartphones, it asks all the time.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a browser related issue rather than a coding issue. In browsers like Chrome this interference in inevitable. It has to do a lot with security concern. Hackers can create a fake webpage for a banking site as a part of phishing and hack peoples password.

Most of the latest browsers disable hiding the location bar, although in some browsers, setting location=no will disable the address bar from being modified.

But from a coding perspective you have some options, Some of them are listed below.

- You can use a localStrorage object that persists any saved data indefinitely on the user's computer and across browser tabs (similar to JavaScript cookies).
  Here is a demo code:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var mydomstorage=window.localStorage || (window.globalStorage?globalStorage[location.hostname] : null)
  if (mydomstorage){
  var i=(mydomstorage.pagecount)? parseInt(mydomstorage.pagecount)+1 : 1
  document.write("You have visited this page <b>" + i + " </b> times altogether.")
  mydomstorage.pagecount=i
  }
  else{
  document.write("<b>Your browser doesn't support DOM Storage unfortunately.</b>")
  }
  </script>
  ```

This code works on FF3+, Chrome4+, Safari4+, Opera10.5+, or IE8+

- If you have windows popping up that ask for the location you can try out this simple solution by making window.open=null; on the instance that is responsible for fetching out the location.